# Why checking isEmpty each row during BufferedReader makes a difference in Java reading file line by line

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a piece of code reading a file. The content of the file is just an id for each line. Nothing special. However, I'm not sure why each style of this code produces different results.

The content of the file looks like this

```
a9c536f6-592f-4458-b61b-6ed3f875e990
d6b384d3-8fae-2dd3-ed06-b57cb65b093c
31474dd6-5c3b-4dc4-82cb-7e05121a77e1
b37dd457-da49-4972-9e3d-cd642e975562
f88df909-35bc-453c-b706-d48b5a11af9a
5d75083b-c4a8-4ad1-8494-645aaabfb283
85d8170e-8982-43c2-b574-9d7fe96d1b46
68bf33d0-1b5e-480c-83f2-ae38d9e0c8c8
26ea9d4a-f509-43b2-850f-cc445dccfd33
f9e9bd88-f67d-4e66-b281-eceeb57985eb
```

```java
    @Test
    void testReadFile() throws Exception
    {
        String fileName = "/Users/user/Downloads/payload";
        // #1
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        Set<String> readUsingCollect = reader.lines().filter(l -> !l.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String row;

        // #2
        Set<String> readUsingNonEmpty = new HashSet<>();
        while ((row = reader.readLine()) != null && !row.isEmpty()) {
            readUsingNonEmpty.add(row);
        }

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        // #3
        String row1;
        Set<String> readNonCheckingNonEmpty = new HashSet<>();
        int counter = 0;
        while ((row1 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (row1.isEmpty()) {
                counter += 1;
            }
            readNonCheckingNonEmpty.add(row1);
        }

        Sets.SetView<String> difference = Sets.difference(readNonCheckingNonEmpty, readUsingNonEmpty);

        System.out.println("Size readUsingCollect: " + readUsingCollect.size());
        System.out.println("Size readUsingNonEmpty: " + readUsingNonEmpty.size());
        System.out.println("Size readNonCheckingNonEmpty: " + readNonCheckingNonEmpty.size());
        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        System.out.println("Difference in size: " + difference.size());
        reader.close();
    }
```

Here's the result from running the above code

```
Size readUsingCollect: 7525
Size readUsingNonEmpty: 5498
Size readNonCheckingNonEmpty: 7526
Counter: 2
Difference in size: 2028
```

I wonder why #2 produces different result than #3 and #1. The content of the file doesn't have empty line. What puzzling me the most is I would expect #1 and #2 to be the same but they are different.

Comment: I highly suspect that there *is* an empty line somewhere in the middle, since  `readUsingCollect` and `readNonCheckingNonEmpty` differ by one. Increment a counter whenever you read a line, and when you reach an empty line, print that counter.

Comment: Try printing out the data you read and compare. Maybe that shows the difference.

Comment: I updated the code to have the counter but counter is only showing 2. But the difference between checking inline isEmpty and not differs by a lot from the size of the set.

Comment: `while ((row = reader.readLine()) != null && !row.isEmpty())` will break if the line is not null and empty

Comment: @Cwift this is the correct answer. Approach #2 stops reading data at the first empty line. Please convert your comment into an answer so that I can upvote it. (and maybe show how to correctly filter out empty lines when using approach #2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cwift mentioned in a comment:

The problem with approach #2 is that

```
    while ((row = reader.readLine()) != null && !row.isEmpty()) {}
```

does not filter out empty lines - it **terminates the loop** at the first empty line.

If you want to read the whole file and just filter out empty lines you need to implement approach #2 as:

```
    Set<String> readUsingNonEmpty = new HashSet<>();
    while (row = reader.readLine()) {
        if (!row.isEmpty()) {
            readUsingNonEmpty.add(row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting it for me. I'm still wondering to know why #1 is different from #3.

Comment: @Cwift well #1 filters out the empty lines (`.filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())`), #3 counts the empty lines but adds them to the result set anyway. Since empty strings are deemded equal there can at most one empty string in the result set and that is why #3 has one more entry in the result set.